# How do I add the results of a MySQL query which splits a column into two to a table?

Tags: mysql, insert, split

I am running the following query on a table, which splits the first name and last name of each person in the Name column of the table into Firstname and Lastname:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as Firstname,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as Lastname
FROM   conference;
```

This works fine.  I would now like to add the results of this to two new columns in the table which I have called Firstname and Lastname.

I tried adding `INSERT conference [Firstname, Lastname]`  to the start of the Query, but that generated an error.  Could someone help with the correct way of doing this?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Actually, don't you want to *update* the existing rows in the table conference with the new fields?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to *update* existing rows with those new fields instead of *inserting* new records, this should work

```
UPDATE Conference 
SET 
   Firstname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),
   Lastname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) as Firstname,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as Surname
into conference 
from conference
```